# Rails 3 link_to to namespaced controller action without model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, namespaces

I have the following Rails controller (this controller has no model):

```
class Admin::AdminController < ApplicationController
  def login
  end
end
```

I am not able to link to this controller action with "link_to".

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your routes.rb:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :admin do
    collection do
      post :login
```

Your link_to

```
<%= link_to "Anything", login_admin_admin_path %>
```

Try this out.